# Configuring live view on external monitor for Nikon D7100 attached to microscope

Tags: nikon, dslr, monitors, microscopy, hdmi

The camera is attached to a professional dentistry microscope and feeds into an external monitor through HDMI.

The live view on the monitor is really dark, and details undistinguishable. However, photos turn out perfect.

I'd like the live view to match the photos (i.e. what the microscope actually sees). What configuration am I missing?

Comment: What you have set in SETUP->HDMI->Output resolution? What is the native resolution of your monitor?

Comment: What is the contrast ratio of the monitor?